# Logging from deploy.fsx in fake deploy

Tags: f#, f#-fake

Is there anyway to show the printf output in the fake.deploy log? It doesnt show the output in the fake.deploy console window or log.

Comment: It does print for me to the console window at least. Show us some code?

Comment: You could try the functions in [TraceHelper](http://fsharp.github.io/FAKE/apidocs/fake-tracehelper.html), for example `logfn`